# ¿Cómo ocultar un formulario HTML al ser redireccionado en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

El form que tengo que está constituido por un input y un botón, al ser validado y guardado en la base de datos y si hubo éxito, después de ser redirigido nuevamente a la página del form, este se oculte y en su lugar aparezca el mensaje "Correo guardado correctamente".

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto? Me imagino que con Javascript pero no se como decirle que lo haga después de ser redirigido y no al cargar normalmente la página.

El código del form es:

```
 <div id="div1">


 <form method="post" id="formulario" action="enviarcorreo.php">
 <label>Deja tu correo electrónico para suscribirte a nuestro           Newsletter</label>
 <br>
 <input name="correo" type="email" id="correo"
 value="" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" style="width:50%" />
 <button id="btn2" type="submit">Suscribir</button>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Código PHP Validación y Guardado

```
    <?php  

    $mail = filter_var($_POST['correo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);


     if($mail){

       $server = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $database = 'bd_newsletter';

     $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

         if (!$conn) {
         die("Error de Conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());
          }

     $mail = $_POST['correo'];

         $sql = "INSERT INTO mails_newsletter (correo_usuario) VALUES   ('$mail')";
         if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            header("location:https://localhost/wordpress");
            }else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);



     }


 ?>
```

Comment: Lo tendrías que hacer con AJAX, al momento de oprimir el boton mandas el valor del input por GET o POST a enviarcorreo.php, si se inserto correctamente mandas un `echo '1'` y si no un `echo '0'` y en la respuesta del AJAX validas esa repuesta si te devuelve un 1, mandas el mensaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería un ejercicio de JS como este, te dejo comentado todo el código.

```js
var btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btn2'); //seleccionamos el boton submit 
  
  btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', enviarCorreo); //agregamos un evento click
  
  
  function enviarCorreo(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //previene el submit para que no te mande a la página de tu action
  let email = document.getElementById('correo').value; // así tomas el valor que haya puesto el usuario
  let divForm = document.getElementById('div1');
  let mensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje');
  let error = document.getElementById('error');
  let su_correo = 'correo='+email;
  console.log(su_correo);
  console.log(email);
  
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {//*Estructura de AJAX con js puro
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();//*
  }else{
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//*
  }
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){//*

  if (xhr.readyState  == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { // *
    var respuesta = xhr.responseText; //capturas la repsuesta del servidor
    if (respuesta === '1'){
      divForm.style.display= 'none'; //oculto el div que tiene el formulario
      mensaje.style.display = 'block'; //muestro el mensaje
    }else{
        error.style.display = 'block'; //caso contrario muestro mensaje de error
      
    }
}

}
//xhr.open('GET','enviarcorreo.php?correo='email,true);//de esta manera enviamos por get el valor de tu input
//xhr.send();
xhr.open("POST", "enviarcorreo.php"); //mandamos por post
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");//esta es una cabecera para que pueda funcionar el envio por post
xhr.send(su_correo);//utilizamos xhr.send para enviar la variable que concatena el 'correo' con el valor como si fuera por GET
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">


 <form method="post" id="formulario" action="enviarcorreo.php">
 <label>Deja tu correo electrónico para suscribirte a nuestro           Newsletter</label>
 <br>
 <input name="correo" type="email" id="correo"
 value="" placeholder="Correo Electronico" style="width:50%" />
 <button id="btn2" type="submit">Suscribir</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 
 <div id="mensaje" style="display: none">El correo fue guardado Correctamente<div>
 <div id="error" style="display: none">Hubo un problema, intente más tarde</div>
```

Tu php quedaría así

```
<?php  


$mail = filter_var($_POS['correo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); //quedaría igual al ejercicio que tenías con $_POST

     if($mail){

       $server = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $database = 'bd_newsletter';

     $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

         if (!$conn) {
         die("Error de Conexion: " . mysqli_connect_error());
          }

     $mail = $_POST['correo'];

         $sql = "INSERT INTO mails_newsletter (correo_usuario) VALUES   ('$mail')";
         if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            //header("location:https://localhost/wordpress");
echo '1';
            }else {
            //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
echo '0';
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);



     }


 ?>
```

Comment: y podria cambiarle que en lugar de GET lo hiciera con POST?

Comment: Sí, deja edito mi repsuesta.

Comment: Listo ya quedo editado y ya lo puedes utilizar con POST, sólo agregue una variable más para concatenar un sitrin 'correo' más el valor del email, para que lo puedas utilizar con POST en el PHP, espero te funcione, recuerda si mi respuesta solucionó tu problema marcala como aceptada, así ganas reputación tú y yo además ayudas a que otros usuarios con el mismo problema sepan cuál fue la solución.

Comment: de hecho, no se si hay algo mal con mi js y jquery o que pasa. Segun entiendo con el ajax no deberia recargar la pagina y si lo hace ademas de que no se oculta el div y tampoco sale el mensaje jejejee. Lo que si, es guardar el correo en la base de datos. No se que pueda ser. Tendra que ver que lo estoy integrando en Wordpress?.

Comment: estoy usando estos cdn <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: AJAX se usa para recargar secciones de tu página web, para no recargar todo el contenido, intenta hacer un console.log(respuesta) para ver el valor que te manda del echo de PHP, tal vez lo que esta fallando es el if.

Comment: con respuesta sale esto:  console.log(respuesta)
ReferenceError: respuesta is not defined[Learn More]

Comment: Que es lo que aparece?

Comment: y cuando corro todo el proceso con la console abierta sale esto: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More] wordpress:39:42

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94025/discussion-between-erick-finn-and-vick-munoz).